# Allow bookmarking with pushState with pure JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, apache, url-routing

I'm developing a pure JavaScript app using Backbone and `pushState`. When I visit http://example.com/, things work fine (it loads index.html). However, when I manually visit a route (http://example.com/someroute), I get a 404.

I understand I need to configure the server to handle this...probably to point back to the index file. How might the VirtualHost config look for this under Apache?

Comment: You could modify your 404 handler to change the status to 200 and serve up your index.html file.

Comment: Awesome...that works great. If you want to answer this question with that, then I will mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your 404 handler to change the status to `200` and serve up your `index.html` file.

Comment: For reference, I ended up doing this: `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html`.

Comment: Be careful that the status is served as 200, otherwise some browsers/spiders may not work properly.

Comment: How can I make sure the status is served as 200? What would the syntax look like?

Comment: Looks like you need to add `Redirect 200 /index.html` before the ErrorDocument line, per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15088830/1355166).

Comment: This does not work, as it produces "The requested URL /ads was not found on this server." I added `Redirect 200 /index.html` above the ErrorDocument line.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure. Been dealing with Node.js far too long.