# Passing incorrect post arguments in www::mechanize

Tags: perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize

I am writing a web scraper and I use `WWW::Mechanize` module. I am performing a post, and pass invalid values to the arguments of the post. What I extracting is all the links from that page and print them to a text file. I would say that it's ok because the text file is empty which means that the page was not found but my problem is that the `success()` method is ok, and the `status()` method is `200`.

I know it sounds a little strange but I try to get a page not found status or something to know that the page is not valid.

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Check `$mech->content` and `$mech->response->as_string` to see what the site really returns. It might return an an error message in HTML but with a HTTP status code of 200.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not your code will work depends on how the target site responds to requests for missing pages. If the server handles it by serving up an error page, you will get a successful (200) response, even though the page you requested isn't there.

[More information from Google on "soft 404s"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=en) -- where missing pages return a valid page.

Here is an example from SO of configuring Apache to return a 200 response instead of a 404:

[How can I replace Apache HTTP code 404 to 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083481/how-can-i-replace-apache-http-code-404-to-200)