# Redirecting all 403 forbidden request to 404 page in aem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, aem

I am trying to redirect all forbidden request to 404 'not found' page. 
Url I am trying to access.
    http://localhost:4503/content/mysite/home.html  (it is working fine).
But when I try to access,
    http://localhost:4503/content/mysite   (it is forbidden here).
My site is developed in adobe experience manager and I don't see any config/setting related with redirecting. So, I have to do something on web server which is Apache here.
And I am not pretty much familiar with Apache and creating rules in it.
I would like to ask if there is anything that redirect any forbidden request
to 404 not found page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a simple rule in dispatcher using /filter section to specify the HTTP requests that Dispatcher accepts. All other requests are sent back to the web server with a 404 error code.

In your case, it could be something like.

```
/filter {
    /0001  { /glob "*" /type "deny" }
    /0002 { /type "allow" /method "POST" /url "/content/mysite/[.]*.html" }
}
```

This will first deny access to all files and then allow access to specific content, which *.html pages under /mysite in this case.

Comment: Would be a good solution. But it will deny other useful  resources in aem, like damadmin, misadmin, crx/de etc.

Comment: above solution works!. I had to add ErrorDocument 404/notfound.html in hppd.conf which is a custom 404 page. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are different options that you can try.

1. If the intent is to display some friendly message instead of the default forbidden message, you can define your own 403 error handler in AEM.
   Overlay the `403.jsp` at `/apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/` and add your custom html for displaying a relevant error message. HTTP response status code would still be 403 in this case.
   Examples can be found in this Adobe's blog. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/customizing-errorhandler-pages.html
2. If you do not want the 403 HTTP status code in the response, you can try to override the status code in the aforementioned `403.jsp`. In the JSP code, if the response is not already committed, you can use `HttpServletResponse.setStatus` API to set the 404 status code. If the response is already committed, this would not work as described in this Sling blog https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/errorhandling.html
3. You can override it in the webserver using `mod_rewrite` or `PHP`. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083481/how-can-i-replace-apache-http-code-404-to-200) shows the options to achieve this.