# How to redirect 404 errors (and 403) to index.html with a 200 response

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I am building a static website that uses JS to parse a URL in order to work out what to display.

I need every URL to actually open index.html where the JS can pull apart the path and act accordingly.

For example `http://my.site/action/params` will be parsed as an `action` with some parameters `params`.

Background, this will be served from AWS S3 via CloudFront using custom error redirection - and this works fine on AWS.

I am, however, trying to build a dev environment under Ubuntu running apache and want to emulate the redirection locally.

I have found a couple of pages that come close, but not quite.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083481/how-can-i-replace-apache-http-code-404-to-200) shows how to do the redirect to a custom error page on the server housed in a file called "404". As `404` is the actual error response code, the example looks a bit confusing and I am having trouble modifying the example to point to index.html.

The example in the accepted answer suggests:

```
Redirect 200 /404
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

which I have modified to:

```
Redirect 200 /index.html
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

However this returns a standard `404` Not Found error page.

If I remove the `Redirect` line, leaving just the `ErrorDocument` line, I get the `index.html` page returned as required, but the https status response is still a `404` code where I need it to be a 200.

If I leave the Redirect line as per the example I actually get the same result as my modified version, so I suspect this is the line that is incorrect, but I can't figure it out.

(I'm using the Chrome Dev Tools console to see the status codes etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution using Rewrite rules instead of error docs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

The key I was missing in this approach seems to be *not* including an `R=???` status response code at the end of the rewrite rule. It took me a while to find that!

As it uses `mod_rewrite` rather than defining error pages I assume that the mechanism is different to how CloudFront does it, but for my dev system needs it seems that the result is the same - which means I can work on the site without having to invalidate the CloudFront cache after every code change and upload.